# Implementation of Distributed Arithmetic Architecture

Tags: digital-logic, fpga

im looking at implementing a distributed arithmetic architecture, but running into some trouble.

From the textbook im looking at  we can rewrite the unsigned convolution of two of two vectors `c` and `x` as

[image]

where the function, f, is a LUT to give the partial sum. It is used as so in the following example:

[image]

However, when it comes to implementation we dont want to use a barrel shifter to shift `b` times every iteration, so the textbook suggests to do the following:

[image]

And I believe that this is implemented as shown in the following circuit

[image]

But I fail to understand how this circuit, and the above example would yield the same results. Let us suppose the same scenario as the example i.e.:

```
c[0] = 2
c[1] = 3
c[2] = 1
```

and

```
x[0] = 1
x[1] = 3
x[2] = 7
```

Then from the circuit we would have the following calculation made when calculating the convolution of x and c (where t is the iteration of the shift adder):

```
t = 0 : y = (0/2) + 6 = 6
t = 1 : y = (6/2) + 4 = 7
t = 2 : y = (7/2) + 1 = 4
```

and obviously this answer is wrong, we can see that `x * c = (2)(1) + (3)(3) + (1)(7) = 18`

So, I ask you, where have I misinterpreted the circuit, what is the problem? Thanks for any help that is given.

Answer (score -1):

(Via Reddit)

[–]bunky_bunk

[+1] 3 points 28 minutes ago
you do not treat bit 0 of the accumulator as the least significant bit. instead you keep a certain number of bits that would be shifted out and discarded. here the 4 bits before the underscore correspond to your equation, but all 6 bits give the result 18 in the end.

```
t=0: 0110_00 (6) [24]
t=1: 0011_00 + 0100_00 = 0111_00 (6/2 + 4 = 7) [12 + 16 = 28]
t=2: 0011_10 + 0001_00 = 0100_10 (7/2 + 1 = 4) [14 + 4 = 18]
```

source: https://old.reddit.com/r/FPGA/comments/jz5v2h/implementation_of_distributed_arithmetic/gda0had/

Comment: If you used an answer or information on Reddit then you should provide a link to the source. What is "bunky_bunk" all about? What does this mean: "[+1] 3 points 28 minutes ago"? Just because you are answering your own question doesn't exempt you from being clear.